# DateTime Convert from int to Month Name in C#, Silverlight

Tags: datetime, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I am trying to print out the *name* of the month not the *integer value* of each month. (for example if the date is 2/2/2002, I would like the "month" to read out "February" instead of "2."

I am pulling in the system.DateTime.now to get the current month.  When I try to print out the current month on the form, it just puts the correlating integer value for the month, whereas I would like to have the Month Name.

I know this can be done using switch-case or if statements to individually convert the numbers into word values, but I was just wondering if there was a simple, built-in conversion command that will automatically tell the application to print out the month's name instead of it's correlating integer value.

I am programming in the Visual Studio 2010 environment using C#-4.0, Silverlight-4.0.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")`

See [MSDN: Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for other format strings.

Comment: Yes, I guess I just couldn't find the right combination of words to put in the search box because I couldn't find this page, this did the trick, though.  Thank you and have a fantastic day!

Comment: You can also use that in XAML binding in Silverlight 4 by binding to a DateTime property and setting the "StringFormat" binding attribute to "MMMM"

Answer (score 23):

You can also get it like this:

```
var month = 7;
var dtf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
string monthName = dtf.GetMonthName(month);
string abbreviatedMonthName = dtf.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(month);
```

Resources:

- [DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName
  Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx)
- [DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName
  Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname.aspx)
- [DateTimeFormatInfo Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6thdx8xz.aspx)
- [DateTimeFormatInfo Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1at0z4ew.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the full date (in your case: February 2, 2002) use:
`myDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")`

For just the month: `.ToString("MMMM")` is correct.